# Qual a diferença entre o servidor HTTP e HTTPS considerando minha estrutura?

Tags: node.js, http, express.js, nginx, https

Eu tenho uma aplicação rest node js rodando atrás de um reverse proxy pelo nginx, com https apropriadamente configurado, em que o servidor é configurado da seguinte forma:
obs: app é meu router.

```
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, () => {
      console.log('hello');
});
```

E o nginx como reverse proxy é configurado da seguinte forma:

```
server {
    server_name example.com example.com.br;

    if ($host !~* example\.com$) {
        return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3003;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com.br/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com.br/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com.br) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com example.virturian.com.br;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

eu consigo acessar a aplicação tranquilamente, tudo está funcionando perfeitamente, minha dúvida é, é necessário ainda, considerando um ambiente de produção, configurar o servidor do express da seguinte maneira?

```
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
httpsServer.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('hello');
});
```

Qual a diferença das duas abordagens, é realmente necessário mesmo já rodando com https pelo nginx, implementar como httpsServer? Outra dúvida, preciso escutar na porta 443 com a segunda abordagem, ou qualquer outra?

Answer (score -1):

Se tu usar https no backend, tem que garantir as seguintes coisas:

O teu programa backend tem que emitir um certificado SSL que o Nginx do teu sistema reconheça como válido. Um guia em inglês sobre como criar certificado para o nome de domínio localhost com um setup parecido com o teu: https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-get-ssl-https-for-localhost/

Esse bloco:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3003;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Precisa ficar assim:

```
location / {
    ## É necessário usar o schema https no upstream
    proxy_pass                    https://localhost:3003;
    proxy_ssl_certificate         /srv/opt/example.com/certificado.pem;
    proxy_ssl_certificate_key     /srv/opt/example.com/chave.key;
    ## Precisa dessas três linhas porque o certificado é auto assinado
    proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /srv/opt/example.com/ca_certificado.crt;
    proxy_ssl_verify              on;
    proxy_ssl_verify_depth        2;
    ## Opcional, ajuda a não gerar uma sessão a cada requisição e fritar a CPU
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse       on;

    proxy_buffering               off;
    proxy_set_header              Host $host;
}
```

Considerando que o certificado, a chave privada do certificado, e o arquivo de autoridade estão em `/srv/opt/example.com`.

A vantagem de usar https no backend é que o tráfego na máquina local também é criptografado, e em alguns cenários isso vai fazer diferença porque dependendo das configurações do nginx, os clientes vão poder ver que o tráfego de ponta a ponta é descriptografado em algum momento.

Não tem como usar porta 443 no backend porque ela já está sendo usada pelo nginx. Mas não é necessário usar essa porta no backend, o importante é respeitar as regras do protocolo HTTPS, e não tem regra pra porta que tu usa.

Aliás, não é necessário usar porta 443 nem no Nginx, isso é um padrão pra facilitar a comunicação pela internet. As portas 80 e 443 vão ficar "escondidas" na barra de endereço dos navegadores modernos se tu usar elas.